# Why Does a mysql Query Using DAYOFYEAR(DATE) Return Different Results to DAY(DATE)?

Tags: mysql

Question as above really.

Just to reiterate I have run two identical queries except for the DAY(DATE) and DAYOFYEAR(DATE) parts which are used in the Select and Group By clauses.

I expected the results to be the same but they differ greatly (DAYOFYEAR returns 344563 results and DAY returns 253637 results). The only explanation I can think of is that January 1st gets grouped with February 1st and so forth because they share the same DAY value. However the result set doesn't seem to show that.

Any confirmation/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see why grouping by a value in the [1, 31] range should render identical results than a value in [1, 366]. What am I missing?

Comment: So it's just because Feb 1st is being grouped with Jan 1st etc?

Comment: Looking for confirmation if that's the case really

Comment: It's because they're entirely different groups. A month can have up to 31 days so you'll get 31 groups at most. A year can have up to 366 days so you'll get up to 366 groups. If you group by week day you'll get up to 7 groups. If you group by colour you'll get entirely different results.

Answer (score 0):

DAYOFMONTH() and DAY() are comparable. today they would both return 16, since today is the 16th of the month, and every month has a day 16. DAYOFYEAR() is a count of how many days since the start of the year. it is something else entirely.